# Show that if $\xi_1 = z + \sqrt{z^2 +1}$, and $\xi_2 = z - \sqrt{z^2 + 1}$, then $|\xi_{1,2}| \le 1$ or, if $\xi_1 = \xi_2$, $|\xi| < 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

Question: Show that if $\xi_1 = z + \sqrt{z^2 +1}$, and $\xi_2 = z - \sqrt{z^2 + 1}$, then $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ satisfy the conditions:

1. $|\xi_j| \le 1$, for $j = 1,2$, and
2. if $\xi_1 = \xi_2$, then $|\xi_1| = |\xi_2| < 1$

if and only if $z$ is purely imaginary, so $z = i\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is real, and $|\alpha| < 1$.

My attempt: Sorry if the question is a little convoluted - this fact is being used to prove root conditions for an LMM, hence the repeated root condition. Anyways, it's easy to show that if $z = i\alpha$, where $\alpha$ satisfies the above conditions, then:

$$\xi_1 = i\alpha + \sqrt{1-\alpha^2},$$
$$\xi_2 = i\alpha - \sqrt{1-\alpha^2},$$

and since $|\alpha| < 1$, $\xi_1 \neq \xi_2$, but we have

$$|\xi_1|^2 = |\xi_2|^2 = 1.$$ So, if $z$ has the form given, the conditions are satisfied, proving the forward direction. I am having trouble with the backward directions. Clearly, if $|\alpha| = 1$, then $\xi_1 = \xi_2$, but $|\xi_1| = |\xi_2| = 1$, which means that the conditions are not satisfied. However, if $|\alpha| > 1$, my proof is very messy that the conditions are not satisfied, and I can't come up with a proof for if $z$ is not purely imaginary at all. I'm hoping that someone can help me with coming up with some hopefully simple proof for the backward direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let us be given $\xi_1,\xi_2,z\in\mathbb{C}$.
Suppose $\xi_1=z+\sqrt{z^2+1}$ and $\xi_1=z-\sqrt{z^2+1}$.

Want to Show (WTS):

$|\xi_1|,|\xi_2|\leq 1$ and $\xi_1=\xi_2\rightarrow |\xi_1|=|\xi_2|<1$ iff $\exists \alpha\in\mathbb{R} (z=i\alpha \wedge |\alpha|<1)$

$(\Longrightarrow)$
Suppose $|\xi_1|,|\xi_2|\leq 1$ and $\xi_1=\xi_2\rightarrow |\xi_1|=|\xi_2|<1$.

WTS $\exists \alpha\in\mathbb{R} (z=i\alpha \wedge |\alpha|<1)$

Let $z=x+iy$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Since a square root is only defined for real numbers, $z^2+1=x^2-y^2+2ixy$ must be a real number, so $2xy$ must vanish. Then $x=0$ or $y=0$.

If $x>0$, then $1<\sqrt{x^2+1}$, so $1<x+1<x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=|\xi_1|$, which contradicts with our assumption that $|\xi_1|\leq 1$.

If $x<-1$, then $0\leq \sqrt{x^2+1}$, so $-\sqrt{x^2+1}\leq 0$, so $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}\leq x<0$, so $|\xi_2|=|x-\sqrt{x^2+1}|=-(x-\sqrt{x^2+1})=-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$.

But then $1<-x<-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=|\xi_2|$, contradicting with the assumption that $|\xi_2|\leq 1$.

If $-1\leq x<0$, $0\leq x+1$, so $|x+1|=x+1$ (1). Also, since $x<0$, we have $x-\sqrt{x^2+1}< -\sqrt{x^2+1}<0$, therefore, $|\xi_2|=|x-\sqrt{x^2+1}|=-(x-\sqrt{x^2+1})=-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ (2). Finally, $2x<0$, so $x^2+2x+1<x^2+1$, so $(x+1)^2<x^2+1$ so, taking roots, $|x+1|<\sqrt{x^2+1}$, which implies $x+1<\sqrt{x^2+1}$ by (1). Then, $1<-x+\sqrt{x^2+1}=|\xi_2|$ by (2), which contradicts the assumption that $|\xi_2|\leq 1$.

We conclude that $x=0$, i.e., $z=iy$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, if $y=0$ as well, we are done, as $z=i0\wedge|0|<1$ means $z$ is a purely imaginary number with length less than 1. (Taking "purely imaginary" to mean $Re(z)=0$, the complex number $0$ appears to be a purely imaginary number.) http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PurelyImaginaryNumber.html

If $1<|y|$, we have $1<y^2$, so $0<y^2-1$, so $\sqrt{1-y^2}=\sqrt{-1(y^2-1)}=\sqrt{i^2(y^2-1)}=i\sqrt{(y^2-1)}$.

Then we have, $|\xi_1|=|iy+\sqrt{-y^2+1}|=|iy+\sqrt{1-y^2}|=|iy+i\sqrt{(y^2-1)}|=|i(y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)})|=|y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}|$ and $|\xi_2|=|iy-\sqrt{-y^2+1}|=|iy-\sqrt{1-y^2}|=|iy-i\sqrt{(y^2-1)}|=|i(y-\sqrt{(y^2-1)})|=|y-\sqrt{(y^2-1)}|$.
Now we have two possibilities: $y<-1$ or $1<y$. 
If the former holds, we have $y<0$, so $-\sqrt{(y^2-1)}<0$, so $y-\sqrt{(y^2-1)}<y<0$. So $|\xi_2|=|y-\sqrt{(y^2-1)}|=-(y-\sqrt{(y^2-1)})=-y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}$
But $y<-1$ implies $y-\sqrt{(y^2-1)}<-1-\sqrt{(y^2-1)}<-1$, so $1<-y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}=|\xi_2|\leq 1$ and there is a contradiction.

If the latter holds, we have $0<y$, and since $0<\sqrt{(y^2-1)}$, $0<y<y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}$. So $|\xi_1|=|y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}|=y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}$
But $1<y$ implies $1<1+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}<y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}$, so $1<y+\sqrt{(y^2-1)}=|\xi_1|\leq 1$ and there is a contradiction.

Therefore, it must be the case that $y\leq 1$, and the forward phase is finished.

$(\Longleftarrow)$

Suppose $\exists \alpha\in\mathbb{R} (z=i\alpha \wedge |\alpha|<1)$.

WTS $|\xi_1|,|\xi_2|\leq 1$ and $\xi_1=\xi_2\rightarrow |\xi_1|=|\xi_2|<1$

Firstly, since $|\alpha|<1$, we have $\alpha^2<1$, so $0<-\alpha^2+1$. Then we have $\xi_1=i\alpha + \sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$ and $\xi_2=i\alpha - \sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$ and $|\xi_1|=|\xi_2|=\alpha^2+(-\alpha^2+1)=1\leq 1$ since $\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}\in\mathbb{R}$ as $0<-\alpha^2+1$, and the first part is done.

Second, since $0<\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$, we have $-\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}<0<\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$, therefore $-\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}\neq \sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$, hence $iy-\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}\neq iy+\sqrt{-\alpha^2+1}$, so $\xi_1\neq \xi_2$ and the second conjunct is trivially true.

Answer (score 0):

Both assertions are false as stated.

1. Let $z=0$, then $\xi_1=1 \ne \xi_2=-1$ and $|\xi_{1,2}|=1 \le 1$,  ***but***  $z=0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is not purely imaginary.
2. Let $z=i$, then $\xi_1=\xi_2=i$  ***but***  $|\xi_{1,2}|=1 \not \lt 1$.

What is true, however, is that:

- $\xi_1 \xi_2=z^2 - (z^2+1)=-1$ $\;\;\implies\;\;$ $|\xi_1| \cdot |\xi_2| = 1$
- $\xi_1 = \xi_2 \;\; \iff \;\; z = \pm i$

Comment: FYI: Unfortunately, your meta comments are censored by the crude mod xander. (please don't flag this one.)